# Showing All Issues ld: framework not found GoogleMaps for architecture

Tags: xcode, frameworks, linker-errors

I resume my problem. First I'm developing a framework that used google maps framework. So when i build the framework the build succeeded. But when I used my framework in a demo project i get this error:
[image]

I tried to find if there is a problem in my search paths framework but i didn't find anythings unusual.
[image: search paths framework]

in the demo project, I import my SDK and I try to configure the key of the google maps service in the AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import MHikes_SDK_Navigation
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let sdk = SDKManager()
        sdk.provideGoogleMapsAppKey("")
        return true
    }
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by downloading the googlemaps Framework not from the documentation of google but from the pod and also integrate it in my framework.